# Google Sheets - How to copy cell to a new sheet and maintain reference

Tags: google-sheets

Say I have a document with 2 x sheets, Sheet01 and Sheet02.
Is there a way I can copy data from Sheet01 and paste it in Sheet02, so that rather than copying all the formulas, the values pasted are a direct reference to the Sheet01 data - i.e. If I update the corresponding values in Sheet01, the data in Sheet02 will mirror?
Thanks

Comment: You need to write formula to `Sheet2`. If it is exact mirroring the simply use `=Sheet1!A1` then copy down and across as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) like `={ Sheet01!A1:D42 }` in cell `Sheet02!A1`.